# Will App Universal linking improve domain ranking?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, backlinks, deeplinks

I build a mobile app. It'll have "share" button, which will be sharing link like `https://example.com/share?some=thing&someother=thing...`

The `https://example.com` itself is a one-page landing.

1. If users will share the deep links on the internet, will it improve search ranking of the landing page?
2. Would it be better to use root url like `https://example.com?some=thing&someother=thing...`? instead of `https://example.com/share?some=thing&someother=thing...`?

Comment: What content is on the `/share` URL?  Does that page link to the home page?    Do the parameters that you are using change the content (Google sees even differences in parameters as different pages)?

Comment: params are not changing content. The web page is static. Just a landing. It has js script that tries to open the app with `myapp://share?some=thing&someother=thing...` URL. If app is not installed, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, deep links will not improve your rankings on Google. However, you may want to look into [App Indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing), which may help your app get into Google's index.

Comment: Links to your site almost always help SEO, even deep links.   In fact deep links are often especially important because they link to specific content that needs links to rank.